# Join two tables with composite key in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm new to hibernate I couldn’t find a solution for this problem.
I have two tables as follows.

```
User
----

Id
fistName
lastName


subscribed
----------

subscribedBy
subscribedTo
```

A user can subscribe to another user. Therefore both **subscribedBy** and **subscribedTo** are user ids and both columns together create a composite key.

For an example user1 has been subscribed to user2 and user3. I want to get the details about user2 and user3 using hibernate entity. But I don't need to get the details about **subscribedBy** user other than id.

Something like this,

```
public class subscribed {

    private long subscribedBy;
    private List< User> subscribedToUsers;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for Hibernate's `@ManyToMany`. No need to create the join table; Hibernate will do that for you:

```
class User {
    @Id
    Long Id
    String fistName
    String lastName

    @ManyToMany
    Collection<User> subscriptions
}
```